# How to change directory in Emacs dired

Tags: emacs, dired

In dired+ in Emacs 23.2.1, how do I navigate to a different directory ("change directory")?

I know how to move up a directory with `^` and how to move to different directory lines with `<` and `>`, but I have been unable to find a command which allows me to navigate to a new directory (by typing in the name) without quiting the current dired window and creating a new one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`C-x C-v` will open a file in the current window.
If instead of a file you give the name of a directory it will open it in dired.

Comment: It does if you finish type `C-j` at the end instead of `enter`. `C-j` will use only what you typed and not try to complete further.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `a` in dired to visit the file/dir at point, discarding the dired buffer you were in, so you don't leave all the ancestor dired buffers around.

And if you use `dired-jump`, then `C-x C-j` can be used from dired *or* file buffers to jump to the parent directory (with point conveniently on the file/directory that you came from).

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(dired-x) Optional Installation Dired Jump")` <kbd>RET</kbd>